# NodeJS: Saving an image sent over HTTP-POST as stream to a file system

Tags: node.js

The following code, an image is saved to file system sent via POST as stream but the saved file is invalid, no matter which image I try.

[image]

Can any body tell me why this code isn't working?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'text/html');

  var imagedata = ''
  req.setEncoding('binary')

  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk);
    imagedata += chunk
  })

  req.on('end', function(){
     fs.writeFile('logo.png', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        })
  })
}).listen(3000);
```

**[Added/updated]**  This is the front-end code to send request to the Node backend in VueJS via the AXIOS HTTP library.

**Sending Request (VueJS-Axios)**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="file" name="file" @change="getFile">
    <button @click="uploadFile">Upload file</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
      selectedFile: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getFile() {

      let file = event.target.files[0]
      this.selectedFile = file
    },
    uploadFile() {
        let fd = new FormData()
        fd.append('file', this.selectedFile)
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/axiosFile',
            data: fd,
            config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
          .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
          })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: POST chunk data in console]

Comment: I don't see any post catch request, can you please drop a console output run?

Comment: Updated. It's all image binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely having problems because you are concatenating the chunks to a string. Encoding the binary data to a string will garble the data unless you encode the data in something like Base64 or HEX encoding.

You can simply keep the chunks as buffers, then concatenate all the buffers before writing the data to your file:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {

    let length = 0;
    const chunks = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
        length += chunk.length;
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
        const imagedata = Buffer.concat(chunks, length);
        fs.writeFile('logo.png', imagedata, 'binary', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                // Send error response...
            } else {
                console.log('File saved.');
                // Send success response...
            }
        });
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

Or you can take advantage of stream piping and let the stream do the work for you:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const imageFile = fs.createWriteStream('logo.png');
    req.pipe(imageFile)
        .on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            // Send error response...
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
            console.log('File saved.');
            // Send success response...
        });
}).listen(3000);
```

---

On the client side a request would look like this:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/axiosFile',
    data: this.selectedFile
}).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Tried first suggestion. It gives `TypeError: "list" argument must be an Array of Buffer or Uint8Array instances  at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:446:13)`

Comment: What data type are you getting for `chunk` (e.g. `console.log(typeof chunk)`)?

Comment: `req.on('data', (chunk) => {    console.log(typeof chunk); .....  }); ` result is  `string`

Comment: The documentation states "By default, no encoding is assigned and stream data will be returned as Buffer objects. Setting an encoding causes the stream data to be returned as strings of the specified encoding rather than as Buffer objects." I would just remove `res.setEncoding('binary')` as that is likely why the first example does not work.

Comment: removed `res.setEncoding('binary')` but still does not work. The saved image is still invalid image.

Comment: Then you are not sending binary data to the server. You have not indicated how you are sending the request, nor have you provided any code. Your question is incomplete, therefore my answer is incomplete. To decode the data on the server you must know the format of the data in the request. If the examples provided are not working for you it's because you are not sending binary data to the server.

Comment: I tried a `.pdf` file (and I believe that's binary data) and that worked with the same code base.

Comment: PDF files are in a proprietary text format, but that does not matter, any file can be sent as binary in a request.

Comment: I've updated the question with the client side code (Vuejs-axios) for sending request. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Also, I tried uploading CSV via firefox and chrome and both time file(s) were saved successfully. Interestingly when I opened the uploaded csv file(s), the initial data in the file(s) contained different data when uploaded via firefox and chrome. Here is the screenshot. 

[csv-uploaded-data](https://monosnap.com/file/FoIVJy2SwaGhu2ms51RyfJC7aJwD9j)

Comment: You're sending `multipart/form-data`, which is not purely a binary format and manually parsing `multipart/form-data` is not trivial. If you want to use `multipart/form-data`, then you should use a more sophisticated server framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/). As it is now your server is not doing any kind of error handling, it will treat every request the same way which is not very good. I updated my answer to provide client code that would work with the server code, but you should look into improving your code and take some time to learn about existing frameworks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the code for multiple file uploads ? Thanks.